# How to get text from hidden field in HTML by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the value out of the hidden field using jQuery. 
My code, where I hide some value is following:

```
(...)$.each(response, function (index, value) {
     $('#notiContent').append(
          $('<li>Nowa wiadomosc : ' + value.Subject + 
          ' od ' + value.Receive + ' data ' + ToJavaScriptDate(value.Date) 
           + ' </li>' + '<li style = "display: none;">' + value.IDMessage + '</li>'))
      });(...)
```

and after the value.IDMessage is hidden, I have to get its value again, and pass to another place. The code is following:

```
          (...)$("#notiContent").delegate('li', 'click', function () {
            var type = $(this).val(); (...)
```

Unfortunately the `type` variable gives 0 all the time. When I changed `.val()` to `.text()` or `.html().toString()` it works, but I am not able to get the value out of hidden field.

How can I do this?

Comment: That's illegal html. a `<ul>` or `<ol`> cannot contain anything but `<li>` elements. a `<p>` inside ul/ol is outright invalid.

Comment: now should be better

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? [According to jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) "*[a]s of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out , I think this is what you want.in this example I have shown you how to get the `hidden` `field` `values` from `static` elements and , how to get hidden field values in  `dynamic` environment.

**note : when you want to assign and get values from hidden field, best practice is to use** `input` **fields with type="hidden"**

try below two examples and try.good luck.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>


<h2>Get the value from static element ---> Note : to get the hidden value, best practice is to use <span style="background-color:red;color:white;">input</span> field</h2>

<div id="notiContentone">
  <li style="cursor:pointer;">Nowa Wiadomosc bla bla bla</li>
  <input type="hidden" id="myhidden" value="give_your_value_here">
</div>

<br><br><br><hr>

<h2>Get the value from dynamic elements</h2>
<div id="notiContentwo"></div>


</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

//get the value from static element implement 
$("div#notiContentone li").click(function(){// in here we choose the li element inside the notiContentone
      var hiddenValue = $("#myhidden").val(); //here we get the assinged value for the hidden field.
      alert(hiddenValue);
});


//get the value from dynamic elements
$(document).ready(function(){
  var createelement_li = $('<li style="cursor:pointer;color:orange;background-color:pink;width:400px;">Nowa Wiadomsc bla bla bla </li>');
  var createelement_hidden_input = $('<input type="hidden" id="myhiddentwo" value="dynamically_added_value_here">');
  $("#notiContentwo").append(createelement_li);
  $("#notiContentwo").append(createelement_hidden_input);
   
  $("div#notiContentwo li").click(function(){
    var gettheHiddenValue = $("#myhiddentwo").val();
    alert(gettheHiddenValue);
  });

});

</script>

</html>
```